# Is it possible to connect Azure Synapse Database(not build-in) using pymssql?

Tags: azure-synapse, azure-synapse-analytics

I'd like to connect the Azure Synpase Analytics (not build-in) database using pymssql.

I tried to connect the build-in database and successfully connect with it.

However, failed to connect the non build-in db( Data Warehouse).

Is it possible to connect Data Warehouse with pymssql or some other drivers?

Please guide me.

Thank you!

Connect Azure Synapse Analytics (Data Warehouse, not build-in db) using python drivers like pymssql.

Comment: you mean dedicated SQL pool?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to connect Data Warehouse with pymssql or some other drivers?

**I tried to Connect with data warehouse using pymssql driver is connecting to built-in db (serverless sql pool) but not connecting to non-built-in db (dedicated sql pool) with same code.**

Instead of pymssql you can use [pyodbc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/python-sql-driver-pyodbc?view=sql-server-ver16) driver to connect non-built-in db (dedicated sql pool) in synapse.

To do this first you need to install ODBC driver in your system from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/windows/system-requirements-installation-and-driver-files?view=sql-server-ver16#installing-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server)

**Sample code:**

```py
import pyodbc
server =  'servername.sql.azuresynapse.net'
database =  'databasename'
username =  'username'
password =  'password'
driver=  '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER='+server+';PORT=1433;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT 1 as tb")
print("connected........................................")
```